# Codes are displayed instead of html elements

Tags: html, ajax, laravel

I have called ajax request in some interval of time. Now, if I pressed the back button after success ajax then, the browser displayed all of my HTML code instead of displaying HTML elements.

```
<script>
    window.setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
            url: '{{route('devices.index')}}',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
</script>
```

```
if($request->ajax()){
            foreach ($devices as $device){
                $latestUpdate = Carbon::parse($device->updated_at);
                $diff = Carbon::now()->diffInMinutes($latestUpdate);
                if($diff > 2){
                    Device::where('id',$device->id)->update(['status'=>'3']);
                }
            }
            return response()->json(['msg' => "successfully checked"]);
        }
```

I had expected to render the HTML elements, but it displayed.

```
{
"msg": "successfully checked"
}
```

Same things happened when I send HTML in json.

```
if($request->ajax()){
            $returnHtml = view('alerts.index', compact('threshold'))
                ->with('alerts', $alerts)->render();
            return response()->json(['html' => $returnHtml, 'data' => $alerts]);
        }
```

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
                url: '{{route('alerts.index')}}',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var formatedhtml = $('<div>').html(data.html).find('table');
                    $('table').html(formatedhtml);
                }
            });
        }, 5000);
```

In this case it display 
[image: HTML code displayed]

Comment: What are you actually doing with the data when you receive it? Are you going to put it into a div, or replace the contents of the current page? `success: function (data) { /* what goes here? document.body.innerHTML=data.html ? */ }`

Comment: I had updated my question, I had done nothing in first and replaced the div in second section.

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you are trying to do. I updated my answer below. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning as json return data as array:

Try something like this

```
return ['html' => $returnHtml, 'data' => $alerts];
```

Comment: That's what he did in his question. Read the last code block. Laravel will convert it to JSON anyway - as he is requesting data as json `dataType: 'json',`

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with how you are receiving the data when you use `return response()->json(['html' => $returnHtml, 'data' => $alerts]);`

If you want to actually put the html that you received from your server into an element in your page, you will need to use `Element.innerHTML` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) so that the html will not be escaped by the browser.

```
window.setInterval(function () {
    $.ajax({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        url: '{{route('devices.index')}}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

        // this is the table where you want to place the received table contents
        var my_table=$('#my-table')

        // we turn the data we received from the server into a jQuery object, then find the table we want data from
        var received_table=$(data.html).find('table')

        // switch out the table contents
        my_table.html(received_table.html())

        }
    });
}, 1000);
```

EDIT: Since you are using jQuery, I changed the answer to fit.